# Adding ECB to search results

Tags: 2010, ecb-menu

I need to add the ECB functionality to the results of a document search (Core Search results).
Does anyone know if this is possible? 
I was hoping to add this through the XSL of the web part but haven't been able to find anyway so far.
If not possible OOTB, anyone have another suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks!